# Mule Esb 3.2.1: gathering the results of a splitter and outputting results as XML

Tags: esb, mule

I've been struggling through SO and the Mule forums but can't find a solution that works.  The esb takes in a single request containing an id, which creates an XML payload that is composed a list of related ids.  This XML payload is then split and sent to a transformer that takes each related id to get some meta data.  The results are then supposed to be combined together to make an XML response.  The problem I am having is that no matter how I transform the final result set, I always get back the document with an encapsulating string "??sr)java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayListx]....""x

Any ideas/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the mule-config I am using:

---

```
<http:connector name="HttpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS"/>
<expression-transformer name="ExtractId" doc:name="Expression">
    <return-argument evaluator="xpath" expression="//string[1]"/>
</expression-transformer>
<flow name="myFlow1" doc:name="myFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="incoming/path/" connector-ref="HttpConnector" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <custom-transformer encoding="UTF-8" class="mycomponents.transformers.SubscriberRequestTransformer" doc:name="Create Hub Id Requests"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>

    <splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="//entry/list/string" enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" doc:name="Splitter"/>
    <transformer ref="ExtractId" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/>
    <logger message="#[payload:]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <custom-transformer encoding="UTF-8" class="mycomponents.transformers.HubQueryProcessor" doc:name="Create Hub Id Requests"/>
    <collection-aggregator />
    <component  class="mycomponents.TopicResponseAggregatorComponent" doc:name="Collect requests" />
    <logger message="Aggregated Content (#[groovy:payload.size()] elements): \n#[payload:]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        
    <logger message="#[payload:]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

---

I've resolved the issue.  Although I don't quite understand why it's different but I'm assuming it has to do with some of the mule "magic".  I split up the flow into multiple flows which is what I was eventually going to do anyways.  However, by doing this the problem went away.

FYI: here's the updated flow:

```
<flow name="myFlow1" doc:name="myFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="url/for/service/" connector-ref="HttpConnector" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="createHubIdRequestsFlow" doc:name="Map To Hub Ids" doc:description="Takes in the situation id passed in by the client.  Does the query lookup versus the content mapping tables.  creates the correspondng requests for meta data information to the provider(s)"/>
    <flow-ref name="getTopicRequests" doc:name="Process Provider Reponses" doc:description="For each JSON response returned from the provider, transform it into an XML representation of that data"/>
    <flow-ref name="buildResponseFlow" doc:name="Build final response" doc:description="piece all the messages together into a single object as a string"/>

    <response>
        <message-properties-transformer>
            <add-message-property value="text/xml" key="Content-Type" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </response>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the message properties transformer stores new properties in the "invocation" scope. You need to set the content-type on the "outbound" scope so it is used by the inbound HTTP endpoint in its response phase.

Try this:

```
    <response>
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property value="text/xml" key="Content-Type" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </response>
```

Comment: no that doesn't work.  all it does is escape all the tags.  if I output the payload to the console before the end of the workflow, everything looks fine.  it returns the XML I want.  But right after that it returns that XML (payload) prepended by
    **??sr)java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayListx]?F??xpwt?  <XML goes HERE>x**

Comment: your suggestion turns that output to have all the tags inside of "<XML goes HERE> escaped.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the log contents for one interaction with myFlow1? You can redact the XML for privacy reason.

Comment: I've resolved the issue by splitting up the flow into separate flows and calling them individually.  The problem now is that it returns the XML as plain text and not XML.  If I change the content type to "text/xml" or "application/xml" i get nothing returned.  If I leave it the way it is, it returns the XML but browsers interpret it as plain text and not XML. No controls appear in Safari or chrome.

Comment: Please show your latest config and also how you did set the response content-type to application/xml.

Comment: thanks for the help. The current issue is the forcing of the content-type at the end, but I think that's due to the fact I return a String from my last transformer.  Although your response didn't quite resolve my problem, it did prompt me to go ahead and refactor my flow.  I'm still puzzled what the refactoring did differently, but I'll have to save that for another time.  I have to finish this prototype before the end of the week.

Comment: I think you are almost there: I've updated my response, let me know if it is OK now.

Comment: as I said before it works.  but I see your point about limiting the scope to outbound.